# Does TNT API allow for automatic login of account?

Tags: api

I would like to build a program that allows me to make an order on a website and send those details over to TNT. TNT is a courier service and I was wondering if I need to login every time, or after a few hours, because I will be logged out of my account when accessing TNT using the API.

Comment: The details I'm referring to are the addresses, and personal information of the buyer of a product that would be delivered by TNT.